# meta-qt5 layer issue (yocto workflow)

Tags: qt5, embedded-linux, yocto

Due to requirements **I need to add qtbase and qml** related packages to a distribution that I already have customised and functional.

To mention that meta-qt5 in its **dunfell** branch (in which I have both my own layer and all its dependencies) is correctly added and these packages are avaibles for my current yocto setup. See example for qtbase

```
bitbake -s | grep qtbase

nativesdk-qtbase                    :5.14.2+gitAUTOINC+3a6d8df521-r0                          
qtbase                              :5.14.2+gitAUTOINC+3a6d8df521-r0                          
qtbase-native                       :5.14.2+gitAUTOINC+3a6d8df521-r0
```

I send a dump of my configuration file below in case you detect any mistakes that I might have missed as I have never worked with the qt layer before.

```
POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION = "2"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

BSPDIR := "${@os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(d.getVar('FILE', True)) + '/../../..')}"

BBLAYERS ?= " \
  ${BSPDIR}/poky/meta \
  ${BSPDIR}/poky/meta-poky \
  ${BSPDIR}/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  ${BSPDIR}/meta-atmel \
  ${BSPDIR}/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  ${BSPDIR}/meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
  ${BSPDIR}/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  ${BSPDIR}/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
  ${BSPDIR}/meta-qt5 \
  "

BBLAYERS_NON_REMOVABLE ?= " \
  ${BSPDIR}/poky/meta \
  ${BSPDIR}/poky/meta-poky \
  "
```

So in my recipe for the image to be generated I indicate that I require the installation of these packages that I have found necessary for what I require (qt and qml) in the usual way as set out below.

```
inherit qmake5

IMAGE_INSTALL += "\
   qtbase \
   qtdeclarative
   qtquickcontrols2 \
"
```

At that point I generate the image using bitbake, and it starts to concurrently run the package fetch (successful), unpack (successful) and configure (successful). But this is where I find the issue that I want to convey to you: **the qtbase `do_compile` step stays indefinitely in an advanced state that never concludes**.

I have looked at the logs and the only record of this problem I can find is when the task starts, but nothing else.

`build/tmp/log/cooker/sama5d2-xplained-sd/console-latest.log`

```
NOTE: recipe qtbase-5.14.2+gitAUTOINC+3a6d8df521-r0: task do_compile: Started
```

What could be happening?

**Build Configuration**

```
BB_VERSION           = "1.46.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "i686-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"
TARGET_SYS           = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE              = "sama5d2-xplained-sd"
DISTRO               = "poky-atmel"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "3.1.13"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "arm vfp cortexa5 neon vfpv4 thumb callconvention-hard"
TARGET_FPU           = "hard"
meta                 
meta-poky            
meta-yocto-bsp       = "dunfell:795339092f87672e4f68e4d3bc4cfd0e252d1831"
meta-atmel           = "dunfell:20eeec4910f1214b9099f5276a944e5d281b70ee"
meta-oe              
meta-networking      
meta-python          
meta-multimedia      = "dunfell:69f94af4d91215e7d4e225bab54bf3bcfee42f1c"
meta-qt5             = "dunfell:b4d24d70aca75791902df5cd59a4f4a54aa4a125"
```

**Qt related `local.conf`**

```
LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST += "commercial"
```

**Additional notes**
If I build the qtbase recipe separately in the same environment I get the same result (to eliminate possible noise).

```
bitbake -c cleanall qtbase

bitbake qtbase

NOTE: Executing Tasks
0: qtbase-5.14.2+gitAUTOINC+3a6d8df521-r0 do_compile - infinite seconds (pid 6857)
```

Comment: I have been investigating and made the default error policy for errors more restrictive in my distro, as well as inheriting from sanity_info in case it would give me more information than a block, and it does, it happens as I said before in the do_compile step of the `meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtbase_git.bb` recipe. Attached [log](https://pastebin.com/fEUA0F1Q)

Comment: what are your PC resources? that build takes a looooong time